# How to pass mount a single file as volume to KubernetesPodOperator?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a docker image that expects a mounted JSON credentials file on startup. The container is started through a command like:

`docker run -v [CREDENTIALS_FILE]:/credentials.json image_name`

This image lives on Google Container Registry and I'd like to start it in a Cloud Composer dag using the KubernetesPodOperator.

Is there a way mount a single file through the KubernetesPodOperator? Ideally, this file would be hosted at a Cloud Storage location. I read that there is a volume/volume_mount options but it seems like a heavy-lift to pass a single file through -- hoping there was another option I'm overlooking.

```
KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                      image="gcr.io/image_name,
                      name="start-container-image",
                      task_id="start-container-image",
                      volume=[?],
                      volume_mounts=[?],
                      dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out using Patrick W's advice and passing a configMap through. I should likely update this to use a secret, but here's the implementation so far:

First I created the configMap:
`kubectl create configmap credentials-configmap --from-file=./credentials.json`

Next, in my DAG I setup the volume options. Notice, I had to modify the mount_path into a sub-directory "/config/" because it errs out when mounting to "/".

```
volume_mount = VolumeMount('creds-volume',
                            mount_path='/config/',
                            sub_path=None,
                            read_only=False)

volume_config = {
    'configMap': {
        'name': 'creds-volume'
    }
}

volume = Volume(name='creds-volume', configs=volume_config)
```

This is passed to the KuberenetesPodOperator:

```
KubernetesPodOperator(
volumes=[volume],
volume_mounts=[volume_mount],
...excluding other options for brevity
)
```

Finally, this is utilized by the container during a startup script like so:
`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/config/credentials.json`

Answer (score 1):

k8s allows you to either mount volumes (a [configMap](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/configmap) for static data would do and is not terribly heavy lifting).
Otherwise, if you need to pull data from remote a remote storage that does not support backing a PV (such as GCS) you'll need to pull the data directly.

You might want to consider using an [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) that will just be used to download the data from your remote storage and save it locally so your main application can run using the data locally.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on David's answer, to fix permission issues with the mounted volume, use the following:

```
volume_config = {
    "configMap": {
        "name": "foobar",
        "defaultMode": 0o744
    }
}
```

Notice the default mode is written as **0o744** in Python 3, as opposed to **0744** in YAML.